# custom user permissions in alfresco

Tags: alfresco

I am using Alfresco Community Edition.

I have 4 Folders.
1. Sales 2. Controller 3. Purchase 4. Accounts.

I have Multiple Users as per their teams.

The Sales Team will create a folder and send the folder to Controller, Controller sends the same folder to Purchase and Purchase to Accounts.

Here, what I want is, when a User from Sales team creates his/her folder, it should be only visible to him/her in Sales Folder and no other Sales user should be able to view it. (Only folder owner should be able to view his own content)

But when the folder is sent to other folders, there too only the Folder Owner and the other users should be able to access and view the folder.

I tried the workflow and I have successfully given the permissions to the other users, but unable to assign proper permissions to the Sales Team.

Short Explanation : Sales Member who creates a folder should be able to access his own folder and not any other members contents/folders in all 4 main folders.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove permission inheritance on the root folder of the site.
2. Set the proper permission to each folder through `Manage permissions` (Sales, Controller, Purchase, Account)
3. Setup a rule to act upon some action or manage the permissions through your workflow.

You can read up on folder permissions [here](http://docs.alfresco.com/cloud/tasks/library-item-permissions.html).

Cheers!

Comment: Been there, done that!
I am facing problem when moving the sub-folder in Sales to another main folder (Purchase)
In Purchase folder, all the Sales team members are able to view the folders made by other members as well.
I do not want them to view other team members folders.
I tried all the Permissions and Rules  but unable to set the appropriate one.

Please help.

Comment: If you have implemented the above mentioned scenario, you are facing a problem when trying to move the folder because the user that performs the action doesn't have the appropriate permissions. 
Regardless whether you try to move it from a rule or through a workflow, the user performing the action mush have `manager` permissions to the folder and at lease `collaborator` permission for the destination folder.

Quick fix would be to execute the action as administrator. I wouldn't recommend you doing this, but if you are on a tight deadline then consider it. :)

Comment: Yes, I tried this and its working fine. :D

I just wanted that Sales members should be not able to view their other team member's folders.

Thanks a lot for the help. Will try to cope up with this workflow. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no embedded function for your expected behavior but it is possible to archive what you expect by defining rules on the 4 main folders which call JavaScripts to run your business logic:

- remove inheritance flag on new / moved objects (only on direct childs
  / folders)
- remove all direct permissions and add only permissions you
  want to add for this folder

The user who created the new folder will always have all permissions because Alfresco has a special role "Owner" which has similar permissions (ALL) like a Coordinator which will be still active when the folder will be moved to another main folder. If the user creating the folder should still have navigation access to the folder when it is moved you need to give Consumer permission on the all 4 folders for the sales team. This will allow to walk into the folders but only to see subfolders if the user has access.